# How can I use pandas Styler.to_latex() if I have a Series instead of a Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pylatex

I've been using the `Series.to_latex()` method to generate a table in my LaTeX doc as it follows:

```
section.append(NoEscape(s.transform(lambda x: f"{x:,}").to_latex()))
```

My Serie looks like this:

```
All channels    1099592
Telefe           158738
El Trece         127082
America TV       109763
TN                64598
El Nueve          43450
A24               37639
C5N               36800
ESPN              29356
LN +              27006
Cronica TV        25140
Name: Total:, dtype: int64
```

But since yesterday my script shows the following output:

```
FutureWarning: In future versions `DataFrame.to_latex` is expected to utilise the base implementation of `Styler.to_latex` for formatting and rendering. The arguments signature may therefore change. It is recommended instead to use `DataFrame.style.to_latex` which also contains additional functionality.
  section.append(NoEscape(s.transform(lambda x: f"{x:,}").to_latex()))
```

But when I try to implement the `s.style.to_latex()` or `s.style.format(thousands = ",").to_latex()` statements I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'style'
```

I'm not sure the style is properly implemented for Series since i haven't found any indication of in in the [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html)

My question here is if there's a way to prevent this warning from happening since it might be depricated in the future, and to optimize my code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error does say the attribute is not for a series, while the warning shows to be applied to a dataframe. I would try:

```
pd.DataFrame(s).style.to_latex()
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(s).style.format(thousands = ",").to_latex()
```